# How to make a ball hang from a rope?

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js

I'm trying to make a simple game using P5.js library where a ball is attached to a pin with a rope and it must not exceed the rope lenght when it falls down.
The ball must fall until it reaches the distance from the pin equal to the rope length. How can I do it? I just need it working with the y axis.

here is some code:

```js
var compound;

function Compound(){
    this.pinDiameter = 25;
    this.pinx = width/2;
    this.piny = height/2;

    this.ballDiameter = 50;
    this.ballx = width/2;
    this.bally = height/2 + 200;

    this.ropeWidth = 4;
    this.ropeHeight = 200;
    this.ropex = this.pinx - this.ropeWidth/2;
    this.ropey = this.piny;

    this.updatePin = function(){
    }

    this.updateBall = function(){
        this.ballSpeed  = this.ballSpeed + 1; 
        this.bally = this.bally + this.ballSpeed;
    }

    this.updateRope = function(){
    }

    this.show = function(){
        ellipse(this.pinx, this.piny, this.pinDiameter);
        fill(255);
        noStroke();

        ellipse(this.ballx, this.bally, this.ballDiameter);
        fill(255);
        noStroke();

        rect(this.ropex, this.ropey, this.ropeWidth, this.ropeHeight);
        fill(255);
        noStroke();
    }
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
    compound = new Compound();
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    compound.updatePin()
    compound.updateBall()
    compound.updateRope()
    compound.show()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hope it helps

```js
var compound;

    function Compound(){
        this.pinDiameter = 25;
        this.pinx = width/2;
        this.piny = height/2;
        
        this.ballDiameter = 50;
        this.ballx = this.pinx;
        this.bally = this.piny + 100;
        this.ballSpeed = 0;
        this.ballGravity = 0.5;
        
        this.ropeWidth = 4;
        this.ropeHeight = 200;
        this.ropex = this.pinx - this.ropeWidth/2;
        this.ropey = this.piny;
        
        this.onPin = function(x, y) {
            let dx = x - this.pinx; 
            let dy = y - this.piny; 
            let dist = Math.sqrt(dx*dx, dy*dy)
            return dist <= this.pinDiameter/2; 
        }
        
        this.ropeheightcalc = function(){
            let dx = this.bally - this.piny; 
            return dx;
        }
        
        this.drag = false;  
        this.catch = function() {
              this.drag = true;
              this.mousex = mouseX;
              this.mousey = mouseY;
        }
    
        this.drop = function() {
              this.drag = false;  
        }
        
        this.updatePin = function(){
            if (this.drag) {
                this.piny = mouseY; 
                this.mousey = mouseY;
            }
        }
        
        this.updateBall = function(){
            this.ballSpeed  = this.ballSpeed + this.ballGravity; 
            this.bally = this.bally + this.ballSpeed;
            
            if(this.bally > this.piny + 200){
                this.bally = this.piny + 200;
                this.ballSpeed = 0;
            }
        }
    
        this.updateRope = function(){
            if (this.drag) {
                this.ropey = this.piny; 
                this.ropeHeight = this.ropeheightcalc();
            }
        }
        
        this.show = function(){
            ellipse(this.pinx, this.piny, this.pinDiameter);
            fill(255);
            noStroke();
            
            ellipse(this.ballx, this.bally, this.ballDiameter);
            fill(255);
            noStroke();
            
            rect(this.ropex, this.ropey, this.ropeWidth, this.ropeHeight);
            fill(255);
            noStroke();
        }
    }
    
    function mousePressed() {
        if ( compound.onPin(mouseX, mouseY))
            compound.catch();
    }
    
    function mouseReleased() {
        compound.drop();
    }
    
    function setup() {
        createCanvas(600, 600);
        compound = new Compound();
    }
    
    function draw() {
        background(0);
        compound.updatePin()
        compound.updateBall()
        compound.updateRope()
        compound.show()
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am proposing a code change to the logic in the distance function as it looks like a typo has it broken. I am going to leave my answer as well because it shows the behavior the question is asking for with less extras. Moving the pin is a nice touch but maybe not directly related to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the OP code here is an example that allows the ball to slide down the rope as if the rope is threaded through the ball and has a knot at the end.

```js
var compound;

function Compound(){
    this.pinDiameter = 25;
    this.pinx = width/2;
    this.piny = this.pinDiameter;

    this.ballDiameter = 50;
    this.ballx = width/2;
    this.bally = this.ballDiameter + this.pinDiameter * 2;
    this.ballSpeed = 1;

    this.ropeWidth = 4;
    this.ropeHeight = 200;
    this.ropex = this.pinx - this.ropeWidth/2;
    this.ropey = this.piny;

    this.updatePin = function(){
    }

    this.updateBall = function(){

    if (this.bally < this.piny + 200){
        this.ballSpeed  = this.ballSpeed + 1; 
        this.bally = this.bally + this.ballSpeed;
    }
    }

    this.updateRope = function(){
    }

    this.show = function(){
        ellipse(this.pinx, this.piny, this.pinDiameter);
        fill(255);
        noStroke();

        ellipse(this.ballx, this.bally, this.ballDiameter);
        fill(255);
        noStroke();

        rect(this.ropex, this.ropey, this.ropeWidth, this.ropeHeight);
        fill(255);
        noStroke();
    }
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
    compound = new Compound();
 setFrameRate(1);
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    compound.updatePin()
    compound.updateBall()
    compound.updateRope()
    compound.show()
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.js"></script>
```

The main change is here within update where we need to check that the ball is not off the rope. We also initialize the ball position to near the top of the rope so we can watch it slide down.

```
this.updateBall = function(){
    if (this.bally < this.piny + 200){
        this.ballSpeed  = this.ballSpeed + 1; 
        this.bally = this.bally + this.ballSpeed;
    }
}
```